# attach timestamp to jpg bytearray

Tags: java, timestamp, arrays, exif

I use sockets to send jpg images from server (android) to client. I want to attach timestamps to these images which are of type `long`. Since these images are already processed by image filters I don't want to save them before transmission, so using `ExifInterface` seems impossible. I therefore tried to use `IIOMetadata` but never got it to work. I dont want to use external libs like senselan.

What is the easiest way to do it? If using `IIOMetadata` is the best way to do it, could you please provide me with a working example on how to attach this to my `byte[]` and extract it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a jpg file and then add 8 bytes to encode the long timestamp, then 
another jpg and 8 bytes of timestam, and so on.

You can detect the end of the jpeg, using what it is commented here

[Detect Eof for JPG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585527/detect-eof-for-jpg-images)

Comment: Thanks Pablo! This is a good idea. However I'd rather not touch the protocol but attach the information to the image, so that it is easier to process the image later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did what Pablo suggested, but attached the timestamp to the front of the image.