# Send EOF when end of image bytes found in stream

Tags: go

I need to decode multiple JPEG images concatenated into a single `io.Reader` coming from a command's stdout. The byte stream may look like this:

```
0xff 0xd8 ... 0xff 0xd9 0xff 0xd8 ... 0xff 0xd9
```

Every image starts with en SOI (Start Of Image = `0xff 0xd8`) and ends with EOI (End Of Image = `0xff 0xd9`)

I need to pass a reader to `jpeg.Decode(r)`

I try to implement a wrapper around the raw stream to send EOF when the bytes exactly reach the EOI and the `jpeg.Decode` then should stop reading. The subsequents `jpeg.Decode` should starts on the SOI.

Some solutions could be in the bufio package but i'm not sure how to implement that. Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Comment: *"send EOF "* - TCP has no such thing as a EOF since TCP has no concept of messages, files etc. It is only a byte stream which ends with shutdown of the TCP connection. If you want to have message semantics you would need to implement these in your own application protocol on top of TCP. A common way is to have a fixed length prefix for each message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This is an command stdout reader. There is no TCP involved. I edited my question to be more precise. Thanks for your help !

Comment: The problem is the same though. stdout is also just a byte stream without inherent message semantics. So either you understand the format of JPEG so that you can detect where it ends or you need to have some explicit marker or length or similar to distinguish between multiple messages inside a byte stream. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585527/detect-end-of-file-for-jpg-images

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich, I see your point. Sadly, I have no control over the input stream. Thanks for you helpful link above.